# Can we obtain $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ from $\sum_{i=1}^n \log a_i$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, matlab

Is there a way to obtain $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ from $\sum_{i=1}^n \log a_i$?  Actually I am trying to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{1000} n!/n^n$ using matlab, but since $n!$ and $n^n$ grows too fast as $n$ becomes large, it is only possible to get $\sum_{n=1}^{k} n!/n^n$ for $k\leq 170$. I have a hint to use the identity $\exp (\log f(x))=f(x)$ to handle this problem, but I cannot see how to use it because I don't know any way to obtain $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ from $\sum_{i=1}^n \log a_i$. Should I use the hint in another way?

Comment: Surely not. You can easily find numbers with $\log a_1 + \log a_2 = \log b_1 + \log b_2$ but $a_1+a_2 \ne b_1 + b_2$.

Comment: Just use $$
\frac{{n!}}{{n^n }} \approx \sqrt {2\pi n} \,e^{ - n} \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{12n}} + \frac{1}{{288n^2 }} - \frac{{139}}{{51840n^3 }}} \right)
$$ for large values of $n$ (say $n\geq 20$). Of course the contribution from the terms after $n=170$ will be rather insignificant.

Comment: Instead of computing $n!$ and $n^n$ separately and dividing (which will indeed lead to problems), I recommend replacing $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ by the equal expression $\prod_{j=1}^n \frac jn$ (which is more computationally friendly in this context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it is only possible to get $\sum_{n=1}^{k} n!/n^n$ for $k\leq 170$." It is not clear to me why do you think this. I assume that you are trying to calculate the numerator and denominator separately for each term of the series:
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{(1\cdot2\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot n)}{(n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot\ldots\cdot n)}$$ and at some point you get overflow $\frac{\infty}{\infty}=\operatorname{Nan}$, since both the numerator and denominator are out of the range of the IEEE double.

But nothing stops you to calculate this way:

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)$$
... and the overflow is gone!

Yet another way to avoid the overflow (following the hint) is to write:

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\exp{\ln\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)}=\exp\left(\ln 1+\ln 2+\ldots+\ln n - n\ln n\right)$$

Comment: I would add that the last formula has the added benefit that $\ln 1+\ln 2+\ldots+\ln n$ can be reused for calculating the next term, thus reducing the algorithmic complexity.